# Calculus: Differentiable and Continuous Reasoning

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)=x^{5/3}+b$ when $x<1$ and $f(x)=ax^{4/3}$ when $x\geq 1$. This question wants to know for what values of $a$ and $b$ is $f(x)$ differentiable for all values of $x$.

When I solved this problem, I set $\frac{d}{dx} [x^{5/3}+b]=\frac{d}{dx}ax^{4/3}$ when $x=1$. So, $\frac{5}{3}=\frac{4}{3}a\implies a=\frac{5}{4}$. This implies that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}f'(x)=c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$ to make the function be differentiable when $x=1$. When the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative at a point are equal, then the function is said to be differentiable at that point. When $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=1$, then we know $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$. This means $\forall b\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ should be continuous at $x=1$. However, this is not the case for certain values of $b$.

> So, what is wrong with my reasoning here...

Now, the answer requires that $b=\frac{1}{4}$ because the function should be continuous at $x=1$. This is because when $1^{5/3}+b=a1^{4/3}$ and $a=\frac{5}{4}$ implies $1+b=\frac{5}{4}\implies b=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Let g(x) = x^(5/3) + b, and let h(x) = a x^(4/3). For the limit of  g(x) as x → 1- to equal the limit of h(x) as x → 1+ (which is necessary for f to be continuous at x = 1), you need 1 + b  = a. Now assuming continuity (i.e., letting a = b+1), you can check the condition making the left- and right-hand derivatives equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning assumes that if $\lim_{x\to d^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to d^+}f'(x)=c$, then $f$ is differentiable at $d$ and furthermore that $f'(d)=c$. That is wrong. Just see what happens if
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  0&\text{ if }x\ne0\\
  1&\text{ if }x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
However, the statement that you were assuming does indeed hold if you add the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $d$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac54$ is the left derivative of $f$ at $1$ only if $f(1)=1^{5/4}+b.$ Otherwise, $f$ is not even left continuous at $1.$

Another mistake is to claim that $f$ is differentiable at $1$ iff $f'$ has a limit at $1$ (i.e. has a left and right limit and they are equal). This is not the definition of differentiability but is (when $f$ is already known to be continuous at $1$) equivalent to $f$ being $C^1$ at $1.$ If you first make sure that $f$ is continous at $1,$ your calculations of the left and right derivative at $1$ are fine but should be expressed as such, and not as (true but useless) left and right limits of $f'.$